# Obtener datos con el menor numero de secuencia

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy EN SQL DE ORACLE
No sé cómo hacer la siguiente consulta, a ver si me podéis ayudar. Tengo la siguiente tabla, en la que hay 2 productos diferentes, insertados en diferentes fechas y horas, y con cantidades diferentes:

```
Producto1 1/12/17 15:30 5u
Producto1 5/12/17 16:00 3u
Producto1 5/12/17 12:12 1u
Producto2 1/12/17 15:05 8u
Producto2 6/12/17 11:45 7u
```

Y quiero que me devuelva de cada producto el registro con fecha y hora más reciente, pero que no se repita el producto. Así:

```
Producto1 5/12/17 16:00 3u
Producto2 6/12/17 11:45 7u
```

Cómo lo hago? Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Nos cuentas que intentaste hasta ahora y donde te trabaste?

Comment: Si pudieras agregar lo que has intentando hasta el momento, seria lo mejor. Recuerda revisar el articulo [mcve] para ayudarte.

Comment: Lo que quieres hacer es una de las cosas más simples y ordinarias en bases de datos. Conviene que investigues, para aprender, que intentes un código y si te falla entonces puedes preguntar aquí mostrando el código que estás usando.

Comment: Hay diferentes maneras de resolverlo, puedes utilizar DISTINCT y a su vez los operadores de MAX Y MIN, o un TOP. Espero te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta lo siguiente, no es el mejor de los queries pero logra el objetivo:

```
select pp.* from tabla_productos pp 
join (select producto, max(fecha) fecha from tabla_productos group by producto) p
on p.producto = pp.producto and p.fecha = pp.fecha
```

Sobre el puedes trabajar y mejorarlo, espero te sirva!